# Border pushing text from center

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the `h1` text on the top center of the page, but when I add a `border` the `width` of the `border` extends the entire top part of the page. When I decrease of the `width` of the element using CSS the `border` pushes the text towards the left.

*Before changing width*

[image]

*After changing the width*

[image]

*Demo :*

#### [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stx6b37d/)

Comment: The border doesn't push the text to the left. The text is pushed to the left because you reduce the width and the element is aligned to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float` property and add `margin: 0 auto` to center `h1` as it is a block element.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stx6b37d/2/)

Comment: Mind me asking what the 'auto' in margin does?

Comment: @IE8IsBetterThenGoogleChrome : browser itself calculates the `margin` property equally from both sides.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin: 0 auto` in your css like this

```
h1{
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid green;
    width: 50%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting this in the css,

```
h1{
text-align: center;
border: 3px solid green;
width: 50%;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

The changes made are: **removed** "float:center;" and **added** "margin:0 auto;"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the float, there is no float for center, just left and right. Because you have declared a width you can use margin: 0 auto which will center your h1. Keep in mind that if you remove the width the margin: 0 auto will not work.

```
h1{
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid green;
    width: 50%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```